# How to compare text

Tags: php, algorithm, compare, stringcomparer

Like the title, How to compare text?. For a example, go to textdiff.com.

Comment: I've changed my answer based on your response. Please take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). This is a fairly general algorithm for identifying differences between two strings.

Comment: No, i want to ask the algorithm. Not a software. But it is good if you give me a php class

Comment: PHP has a `levenshtein()` function you can look into.

Comment: Levensthein measures the "amount of difference" between two strings, but will not return the location of the differences. Also, I am not sure how useful it is for comparing sentences. `Text_Diff` will do exactly what the OP asked for (see my answer for links)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at Pear's `Text_Diff`

http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/

Comment: @Snoob: Yes, `Text_Diff` is one of the classes of the Pear framework. You will have to install the base Pear components first (see http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.introduction.php ) and, once that is working you can add Text_Diff. Looking at the page you linked I would say that's what they used. `Text_Diff` comes with documentation and examples: http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/docs/latest/

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a terminal command, check out diff, found in linux by default. You can also have it on windows by installing cygwin [with a LOT of excess baggage. :\ ]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Jaccard's Similarity coefficient. Treating each sentence as a unit.